# Using T-SQL is there a way to show the name of a database being backed up or restored?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-backups, database-restore

I have some code I use to monitor backup & restores, give me a "microsoft minute" of when it ***may*** be done, how long it's been running, and a few other pieces of information.  The code is below:

```
WITH CTE
AS (
SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS [ServerName]
    ,db_name(r.database_id) AS DatabaseName
    ,CONVERT(NUMERIC(6, 2), r.percent_complete) AS [PercentComplete]
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), DATEADD(ms, r.estimated_completion_time, GetDate()), 20) AS [ETACompletionTime]
    ,CONVERT(NUMERIC(10, 2), r.total_elapsed_time / 1000.0 / 60.0) AS [ElapsedMinutes]
    ,CONVERT(NUMERIC(10, 2), r.total_elapsed_time / 1000.0 / 60.0 / 60.0) AS [ElapsedHours]
    ,CONVERT(NUMERIC(10, 2), r.estimated_completion_time / 1000.0 / 60.0) AS [ETAMinutes]
    ,CONVERT(NUMERIC(10, 2), r.estimated_completion_time / 1000.0 / 60.0 / 60.0) AS [ETAHours]
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(1000), (
            SELECT SUBSTRING(TEXT, r.statement_start_offset / 2, CASE 
                        WHEN r.statement_end_offset = - 1
                            THEN 1000
                        ELSE (r.statement_end_offset - r.statement_start_offset) / 2
                        END)
            FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) --sql_handle is a column from sys.dm_exec_requests
            )) AS [TSQLCode]
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests r
WHERE command IN (
        'RESTORE DATABASE'
        ,'BACKUP DATABASE'
        )
)
SELECT [ServerName]
,SUBSTRING([TSQLCode], CHARINDEX('DATABASE [', [TSQLCode]) + 10, CHARINDEX(']', [TSQLCode], (CHARINDEX('DATABASE [', [TSQLCode]) + 10)) - (CHARINDEX('DATABASE [', [TSQLCode]) + 10)) AS [DatabaseName]
,[PercentComplete]
,[ETACompletionTime]
,[ElapsedMinutes]
,[ElapsedHours]
,[ETAMinutes]
,[ETAHours]
,Cast(CASE 
        WHEN charindex('Rest', [TSQLCode], 0) > 0
            THEN 'Restoring'
        ELSE 'Backup'
        END AS VARCHAR(10)) AS BackupRestore
,[TSQLCode]
FROM CTE
```

This code, for the most part, works...as long as the database is encapsulated with [databasename] (square brackets).  If it is not, you will get the following error.

[image: Invalid length error]

With all the databases we have to restore, with the many, many jobs we have that are doing the restores, I don't know which jobs do or do not have the square brackets.  And I have to account for ad-hoc backup\restore jobs from people that may not be using the square brackets.

So I am looking for a way to grab the database, without parsing, that is being backed up or restored.

Answer (score 2):

swapping charindex with `patindex('%DATABASE[ \[]%', [TSQLCode])` will mess with your +10, might be easier to just replace backup database and restore database, ltrim and charindex ' ' to pull the word after. I did not test the "code" below but it looked right to me. fiddle at will!

```
left(ltrim(replace(replace(TSQLCode, 'backup database',''),'restore database','')),charindex(' ',ltrim(replace(replace(TSQLCode, 'backup database',''),'restore database',''))))
```

edit: now that I have sql server in front of me, try:

```
WITH CTE
AS (
SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS [ServerName]
    ,db_name(r.database_id) AS DatabaseName
    ,CONVERT(NUMERIC(6, 2), r.percent_complete) AS [PercentComplete]
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), DATEADD(ms, r.estimated_completion_time, GetDate()), 20) AS [ETACompletionTime]
    ,CONVERT(NUMERIC(10, 2), r.total_elapsed_time / 1000.0 / 60.0) AS [ElapsedMinutes]
    ,CONVERT(NUMERIC(10, 2), r.total_elapsed_time / 1000.0 / 60.0 / 60.0) AS [ElapsedHours]
    ,CONVERT(NUMERIC(10, 2), r.estimated_completion_time / 1000.0 / 60.0) AS [ETAMinutes]
    ,CONVERT(NUMERIC(10, 2), r.estimated_completion_time / 1000.0 / 60.0 / 60.0) AS [ETAHours]
    ,replace(replace(CONVERT(VARCHAR(1000), (
            SELECT replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(SUBSTRING(TEXT, r.statement_start_offset / 2, CASE 
                        WHEN r.statement_end_offset = - 1
                            THEN 1000
                        ELSE (r.statement_end_offset - r.statement_start_offset) / 2
                        END),']',''),'[',''),char(10),' '),char(13), ' '),char(9), ' '),'  ',' ')
            FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) --sql_handle is a column from sys.dm_exec_requests
            )),'  ',' '),'  ',' ') AS [TSQLCode]
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests r
WHERE command IN (
        'RESTORE DATABASE'
        ,'BACKUP DATABASE'
        )
)
SELECT [ServerName]
,SUBSTRING([TSQLCode], CHARINDEX('DATABASE ', [TSQLCode]) + 9, CHARINDEX(' ', [TSQLCode], (CHARINDEX('DATABASE ', [TSQLCode]) + 9)) - (CHARINDEX('DATABASE ', [TSQLCode]) + 9)) AS [DatabaseName]
,[PercentComplete]
,[ETACompletionTime]
,[ElapsedMinutes]
,[ElapsedHours]
,[ETAMinutes]
,[ETAHours]
,Cast(CASE 
        WHEN charindex('Rest', [TSQLCode], 0) > 0
            THEN 'Restoring'
        ELSE 'Backup'
        END AS VARCHAR(10)) AS BackupRestore
,[TSQLCode]
FROM CTE
```

updated to remove (\n\r\t) (new line, carriage return, tab) and "try" to clean up enough of the double spaces to not mess with your output.

one of the many times knowing your [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/) is good.

removing [] in cte, then processing for no [], worked on my tests here.

Comment: As it stands now, no errors when used on backup code without square brackets but it is picking up the word TO after the database name.  
With the square brackets, there is no database name at all.
I am taking your advice and fiddling with it.  Looks to be a good starting point.  Will report findings.  And Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: thanks for the welcome! only 20 years late arriving, though dunno if SO was around then. I put a working example with the least amount of code change in my answer, not with patindex(), just removing the brackets and processing as needed for the loss of them. It'll work from what my tests showed.

Comment: This is working as it should now!  Thanks!  
One more thing I just discovered today is if the t-sql code is formatted in any way (example a carriage return after the database name to put code on the next line) it will mess up what you fixed for me.  Not sure how to account for that.  But you have me moved to the next hurdle.  Thanks again!

Comment: added the "fixes" to the answer :) double spaces are the devil....I did 3 replaces just for them and it's still may be possible for them to appear. silliness. should work on 99.999% of all formatting choices.